# How do I solve error 'missing revert data in call exception'?

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-deployment, sepolia

I'm trying to withdraw donations from a single campaign. When I click the withdraw button it loads then reverts with the error;

```
Error occurred while withdrawing funds Error: 


╔═══════════════════╗
║ TRANSACTION ERROR ║
╚═══════════════════╝

Reason: missing revert data in call exception; Transaction reverted without a reason string


╔═════════════════════════╗
║ TRANSACTION INFORMATION ║
╚═════════════════════════╝

from:      0x7F000649C3f42C2D80dc3bd99F3F5e7CB737092C
to:        0x16693689ce65Cd886a281b2Bb86c6bbc26aAc206 (CrowdFunding)
chain:     sepolia (11155111)
rpc:       sepolia.rpc.thirdweb.com
data:      0x388a7ec10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
method:    withdrawDonations(0)


╔═════════════════════╗
║ DEBUGGING RESOURCES ║
╚═════════════════════╝

Need helping debugging? Join our Discord: https://discord.gg/thirdweb


    at ContractWrapper.formatError (contract-publisher-7f0a5ce8.browser.esm.js:7754:12)
    at async ContractWrapper.sendTransactionByFunction (contract-publisher-7f0a5ce8.browser.esm.js:7696:17)
    at async ContractWrapper.sendTransaction (contract-publisher-7f0a5ce8.browser.esm.js:7652:18)
    at async ContractWrapper.call (contract-publisher-7f0a5ce8.browser.esm.js:7611:23)
    at async withdraw (index.jsx:104:20)
    at async handleWithdraw (WithdrawFromCampaigns.jsx:30:5)
```

I logged both state and `state.pId` and they both have the right values. I have no idea why withdraw would fail. Below are important snippets. You can see the full codes in [My Repo](https://github.com/kihiuFrank/CrowdFunding)

###### WithdrawFromCampaigns component (handleWithdraw function)

```
  const handleWithdraw = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    console.log("state", state.pId);

    await withdraw(state.pId);

    navigate("/");
    setIsLoading(false);
  };
```

###### withdraw function (interacting with our contract)

```
  const withdraw = async (pId) => {
    try {
      const data = await contract.call("withdrawDonations", [pId]);
      toast.success("Campaign funds successfully withdrawn.");
      return data;
    } catch (err) {
      toast.error("Error occurred while withdrawing funds.");
      console.log("Error occurred while withdrawing funds", err);
    }
  };
```